# List comprehension vs map

Tags: python, list-comprehension, map-function

Is there a reason to prefer using [map()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map) over list comprehension or vice versa?  Is either of them generally more efficient or considered generally more Pythonic than the other?

Comment: Note that PyLint warns if you use map instead of list comprehension, see [message W0141](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0141).

Comment: @lumbric, I'm not sure but it does only if lambda is used in map.

Comment: I made a 17 minute tutorial on list comp vs map if anyone finds it useful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNW6Tbp59HQ

Comment: The title of the YouTube video is *"Python - List comprehension vs map function tutorial (speed, lambda, history, examples)"*.

Answer (score 853, accepted):

*map* may be microscopically faster in some cases (when you're *not* making a lambda for the purpose, but using the same function in map and a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python)). List comprehensions may be faster in other cases and most (not all) Pythonistas consider them more direct and clearer.

An example of the tiny speed advantage of *map* when using exactly the same function:

```
$ python -m timeit -s'xs=range(10)' 'map(hex, xs)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.86 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s'xs=range(10)' '[hex(x) for x in xs]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.58 usec per loop
```

An example of how performance comparison gets completely reversed when map needs a lambda:

```
$ python -m timeit -s'xs=range(10)' 'map(lambda x: x+2, xs)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.24 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s'xs=range(10)' '[x+2 for x in xs]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.32 usec per loop
```

Comment: Thanks.  It sounds like list comprehensions are the way to go in most cases.

Comment: Yep, indeed our internal Python style guide at work explicitly recomments listcomps against map and filter (not even mentioning the tiny but measurable performance improvement map can give in some cases;-).

Comment: Not to kibash on Alex's infinite style points, but sometimes map seems easier to read to me:   data = map(str, some_list_of_objects).  Some other ones... operator.attrgetter, operator.itemgetter, etc.

Comment: `map(operator.attrgetter('foo'), objs)` easier to read than `[o.foo for o in objs]` ?!

Comment: Alex, you're not as lazy as me.... I usually have "from operator import itemgetter as iget, attrgetter as aget" for that very reason!

Comment: @Alex: I prefer not to introduce unnecessary names, like `o` here, and your examples show why.

Comment: I think that @GreggLind has a point, with his `str()` example, though.

Comment: @AlexMartelli But… `map(operator.attrgetter('foo'), objs)` and `[o.foo for foo in objs]` don't do the same .-. and where does come from the `o`? If you meant `[foo.foo for foo in objs]`, I'm even more skeptical on which one is actually easier to read (Yeah I know, 4 years later)

Comment: I thought list comprehensions were only faster when you were using all their functionality (`map`, `lambda` and `filter`)??

Comment: Yes, as JeromeJ noted, if you have to combine filter + map, comprehension has advantage                                        `$> python -mtimeit -s 's="abcd"*100' '[x.upper() for x in s if x<"c"]'`
10000 loops, best of 3: **73 usec** per loop
`$> python -mtimeit -s 's="abcd"*100'  'map(str.upper,filter(lambda x:x<"c",s))'`
10000 loops, best of 3: **147 usec** per loop

Comment: FWIW, I believe he means `[o.foo for o in objs]`, not `[o.foo for foo in objs]`

Comment: In current versions, the situation is *very* different. On my machine (Windows 8.1, Python 3.4, reference C implementation), all configurations of list comprehensions or `list(map(...))` with `lambda` or explicitly defined functions are about the same speed, despite the explicit `list` call that's now needed. Meanwhile, an equivalent use of a builtin function or method is over twice as fast. (My tests used `def test(x): return x + 1`, `lambda x: x + 1` or `(1).__add__` as the functions applied to `range(100)`.)

Comment: @AttilaSzlovencsák and KarlKnechtel, here is an [ipynb notebook](https://gist.github.com/mamrehn/0f90fad6cf1c84dd621e1947d808e07f) with timings to the tests you provided. Seems like for non-lambda functions, using map is (still, with CPython v3.5.2) slightly faster than list comprehension. For lambda functions, one should use list comprehensions.

Comment: `lines = map (str.strip, open (filename, 'r'))`. Truly perlesque, but also in the bad way. We avoided doing a lookup of "strip" on every instance of string we read from the file but we also forgot to expressly declare we want an iterable so we built a list: producing a generator expression would enable a better overall flow.

Comment: Gregg Lind, Alez Martelli: The argument of readability is good, but also quite subjective. It depends on what you are used to and what's your coding background. List comps. are very intuitive to me now.
@Reid Barton: I don't find the names thing a problem, since there are work-arounds for that, like:    j = [_ for _ in l]   or more memory efficient substituting the variables just by doing:   j = [j for j in l]. Also, check this out:  https://leadsift.com/loop-map-list-comprehension/

Comment: It is crazy because this gives me something different. When I run the python command above, the `map()`  approach takes lesser time even with the lambda expression.

`10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.141 usec per loop` for `map()` and 

`1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.382 usec per loop` for listcomps.
```
I wish to ask if `map()` with lambda will always be slower than its corresponding listcomps or it is not always the case.

Comment: I don't agree with more direct and clear in general, to me `map(int, stuff)` is a lot more clear than `[int(x) for x in stuff]`, no need for a random variable.  it depends on if you have functional experience or not.  map has been around a lot longer than list comprehensions as well.  each serves its purpose, and both should be tools in your tool belt.  Also map is lazy so you can pass it around until you need it whereas the comp will be done on the line it's written.

Comment: In Python 3 the `map` version will produce an iterator which means it will use less memory than the list comprehension. This makes it much faster than list comprehensions. Using a generator comprehension is closer but still slower.

Comment: One of the best coding practices in any language is to reuse existing code, and **especially avoid hand-coding a loop/comprehension where a standard algorithm can do the job**. Algorithm's name states the intent and its implementation does exactly that, whereas a loop requires extra time and energy to parse the implementation and figure the intent in one's head, however trivial the implementation is. Standard algorithms' implementation is likely to perform better, and on 2021-11-29 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, **Python 3.8 `map` is 7x faster on your first `timeit` example and 3.5x on the second**.

Comment: This isn't an entirely fair comparison, as in the map() example you're creating an iterator, while in the comprehension example you're creating an iterator and then unpacking it into a list. If you also an an unpacking expression (or, alternatively, refactor your code into generator comprehension) map() still _should_ be faster, but by a slightly smaller amount.

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges: `map` creates an iterator in O(1) time, while the list comprehension computes the results in O(n) time, where n is the length of `xs`.

Please check by using `xs=range(100000)` and see that the list comprehension is orders of magnitude slower.
For a fairer comparison you should compare `map` with a generator expression.

Comment: Also, I think, maps are lazily evaluated as opposed to list comprehensions. Sometimes you might need that. However, one could, also, use generator comprehensions for laziness in order to have similar syntax as list comprehensions.

Answer (score 600):

**Cases**

- **Common case**: Almost always, you will want to use a list comprehension in *python* because it will be more obvious what you're doing to novice programmers reading your code. (This does not apply to other languages, where other idioms may apply.) It will even be more obvious what you're doing to python programmers, since list comprehensions are the de-facto standard in python for iteration; they are *expected*.
- **Less-common case**: However if you *already have a function defined*, it is often reasonable to use `map`, though it is considered 'unpythonic'. For example, `map(sum, myLists)` is more elegant/terse than `[sum(x) for x in myLists]`. You gain the elegance of not having to make up a dummy variable (e.g. `sum(x) for x...` or `sum(_) for _...` or `sum(readableName) for readableName...`) which you have to type twice, just to iterate. The same argument holds for `filter` and `reduce` and anything from the `itertools` module: if you already have a function handy, you could go ahead and do some functional programming. This gains readability in some situations, and loses it in others (e.g. novice programmers, multiple arguments)... but the readability of your code highly depends on your comments anyway.
- **Almost never**: You may want to use the `map` function as a pure abstract function while doing functional programming, where you're mapping `map`, or currying `map`, or otherwise benefit from talking about `map` as a function. In Haskell for example, a functor interface called `fmap` generalizes mapping over any data structure. This is very uncommon in python because the python grammar compels you to use generator-style to talk about iteration; you can't generalize it easily. (This is sometimes good and sometimes bad.) You can probably come up with rare python examples where `map(f, *lists)` is a reasonable thing to do. The closest example I can come up with would be `sumEach = partial(map,sum)`, which is a one-liner that is very roughly equivalent to:

```
def sumEach(myLists):
    return [sum(_) for _ in myLists]
```

- **Just using a `for`-loop**: You can also of course just use a for-loop. While not as elegant from a functional-programming viewpoint, sometimes non-local variables make code clearer in imperative programming languages such as python, because people are very used to reading code that way. For-loops are also, generally, the most efficient when you are merely doing any complex operation that is not building a list like list-comprehensions and map are optimized for (e.g. summing, or making a tree, etc.) -- at least efficient in terms of memory (not necessarily in terms of time, where I'd expect at worst a constant factor, barring some rare pathological garbage-collection hiccuping).

**"Pythonism"**

I dislike the word "pythonic" because I don't find that pythonic is always elegant in my eyes. Nevertheless, `map` and `filter` and similar functions (like the very useful `itertools` module) are probably considered unpythonic in terms of style.

**Laziness**

In terms of efficiency, like most functional programming constructs, **MAP CAN BE LAZY**, and in fact is lazy in python. That means you can do this (in *python3*) and your computer will not run out of memory and lose all your unsaved data:

```
>>> map(str, range(10**100))
<map object at 0x2201d50>
```

Try doing that with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [str(n) for n in range(10**100)]
# DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME OR YOU WILL BE SAD #
```

Do note that list comprehensions are also inherently lazy, but *python has chosen to implement them as non-lazy*. Nevertheless, python does support lazy list comprehensions in the form of generator expressions, as follows:

```
>>> (str(n) for n in range(10**100))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xacbdef>
```

You can basically think of the `[...]` syntax as passing in a generator expression to the list constructor, like `list(x for x in range(5))`.

**Brief contrived example**

```
from operator import neg
print({x:x**2 for x in map(neg,range(5))})

print({x:x**2 for x in [-y for y in range(5)]})

print({x:x**2 for x in (-y for y in range(5))})
```

List comprehensions are non-lazy, so may require more memory (unless you use generator comprehensions). The square brackets `[...]` often make things obvious, especially when in a mess of parentheses. On the other hand, sometimes you end up being verbose like typing `[x for x in...`. As long as you keep your iterator variables short, list comprehensions are usually clearer if you don't indent your code. But you could always indent your code.

```
print(
    {x:x**2 for x in (-y for y in range(5))}
)
```

or break things up:

```
rangeNeg5 = (-y for y in range(5))
print(
    {x:x**2 for x in rangeNeg5}
)
```

**Efficiency comparison for python3**

`map` is now lazy:

```
% python3 -mtimeit -s 'xs=range(1000)' 'f=lambda x:x' 'z=map(f,xs)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.336 usec per loop            ^^^^^^^^^
```

*Therefore if you will not be using all your data, or do not know ahead of time how much data you need, `map` in python3 (and generator expressions in python2 or python3) will avoid calculating their values until the last moment necessary. Usually this will usually outweigh any overhead from using `map`. The downside is that this is very limited in python as opposed to most functional languages: you only get this benefit if you access your data left-to-right "in order", because python generator expressions can only be evaluated the order `x[0], x[1], x[2], ...`.*

However let's say that we have a pre-made function `f` we'd like to `map`, and we ignore the laziness of `map` by immediately forcing evaluation with `list(...)`. We get some very interesting results:

```
% python3 -mtimeit -s 'xs=range(1000)' 'f=lambda x:x' 'z=list(map(f,xs))'                                                                                                                                                
10000 loops, best of 3: 165/124/135 usec per loop        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    for list(<map object>)

% python3 -mtimeit -s 'xs=range(1000)' 'f=lambda x:x' 'z=[f(x) for x in xs]'                                                                                                                                      
10000 loops, best of 3: 181/118/123 usec per loop        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    for list(<generator>), probably optimized

% python3 -mtimeit -s 'xs=range(1000)' 'f=lambda x:x' 'z=list(f(x) for x in xs)'                                                                                                                                    
1000 loops, best of 3: 215/150/150 usec per loop         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    for list(<generator>)
```

In results are in the form AAA/BBB/CCC where A was performed with on a circa-2010 Intel workstation with python 3.?.?, and B and C were performed with a circa-2013 AMD workstation with python 3.2.1, with extremely different hardware. The result seems to be that map and list comprehensions are comparable in performance, which is most strongly affected by other random factors. The only thing we can tell seems to be that, oddly, while we expect list comprehensions `[...]` to perform better than generator expressions `(...)`, `map` is ALSO more efficient that generator expressions (again assuming that all values are evaluated/used).

It is important to realize that these tests assume a very simple function (the identity function); however this is fine because if the function were complicated, then performance overhead would be negligible compared to other factors in the program. (It may still be interesting to test with other simple things like `f=lambda x:x+x`)

If you're skilled at reading python assembly, you can use the `dis` module to see if that's actually what's going on behind the scenes:

```
>>> listComp = compile('[f(x) for x in xs]', 'listComp', 'eval')
>>> dis.dis(listComp)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x2511a48, file "listComp", line 1>) 
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0 
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (xs) 
              9 GET_ITER             
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
             13 RETURN_VALUE         
>>> listComp.co_consts
(<code object <listcomp> at 0x2511a48, file "listComp", line 1>,)
>>> dis.dis(listComp.co_consts[0])
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0 
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0) 
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                18 (to 27) 
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (x) 
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f) 
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (x) 
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
             21 LIST_APPEND              2 
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6 
        >>   27 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
>>> listComp2 = compile('list(f(x) for x in xs)', 'listComp2', 'eval')
>>> dis.dis(listComp2)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x255bc68, file "listComp2", line 1>) 
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0 
              9 LOAD_NAME                1 (xs) 
             12 GET_ITER             
             13 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
             19 RETURN_VALUE         
>>> listComp2.co_consts
(<code object <genexpr> at 0x255bc68, file "listComp2", line 1>,)
>>> dis.dis(listComp2.co_consts[0])
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0) 
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                17 (to 23) 
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x) 
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f) 
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (x) 
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
             18 YIELD_VALUE          
             19 POP_TOP              
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3 
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
>>> evalledMap = compile('list(map(f,xs))', 'evalledMap', 'eval')
>>> dis.dis(evalledMap)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list) 
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (map) 
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (f) 
              9 LOAD_NAME                3 (xs) 
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

It seems it is better to use `[...]` syntax than `list(...)`. Sadly the `map` class is a bit opaque to disassembly, but we can make due with our speed test.

Comment: "the very useful itertools module [is] probably considered unpythonic in terms of style". Hmm. I don't like the term "Pythonic" either, so in some sense I don't care what it means, but I don't think it's fair to those who do use it, to say that according to "Pythonicness" builtins `map` and `filter` along with standard library `itertools` are inherently bad style. Unless GvR actually says they were either a terrible mistake or solely for performance, the only natural conclusion if that's what "Pythonicness" says is to forget about it as stupid ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Actually, [Guido thought dropping `map`/`filter` was a great idea for Python 3](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196), and only a rebellion by other Pythonistas kept them in the built-in namespace (while `reduce` was moved to `functools`). I personally disagree (`map` and `filter` are fine with predefined, particularly built-in, functions, just never use them if a `lambda` would be needed), but GvR has basically called them not Pythonic for years.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: true, but was GvR ever planning to remove `itertools`? The part I quote from this answer is the main claim that befuddles me. I don't know whether in his ideal world, `map` and `filter` would move to `itertools` (or `functools`) or go entirely, but whichever is the case, once one says that `itertools` is unPythonic in its entirety, then I don't really know what "Pythonic" is supposed to mean but I don't think it can be anything similar to "what GvR recommends people use".

Comment: @SteveJessop: I was only addressing `map`/`filter`, not `itertools`. Functional programming is perfectly Pythonic (`itertools`, `functools` and `operator` were all designed specifically with functional programming in mind, and I use functional idioms in Python all the time), and `itertools` provides features that would be a pain to implement yourself, It's specifically `map` and `filter` being redundant with generator expressions that made Guido hate them. `itertools` has always been fine.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. When the function has no output (e.g. change values of an array in place), which method is faster?

Comment: One extra point I'd add to this very complete and now also ancient answer is that a _list_ comprehension will, imo, always be preferable to `list(map(foo, x))`. Since python 3, if you need a list and not a generator, I don't see any case where `map`, `filter` and the likes are more readable than a list comprehension. The rest of your argument for generator comprehensions stands.

Answer (score 112):

### Python 2: You should use `map` and `filter` instead of list comprehensions.

An **objective** reason why you should prefer them even though they're not "Pythonic" is this:
They require functions/lambdas as arguments, which **introduce a new scope**.

I've gotten bitten by this more than once:

```
for x, y in somePoints:
    # (several lines of code here)
    squared = [x ** 2 for x in numbers]
    # Oops, x was silently overwritten!
```

but if instead I had said:

```
for x, y in somePoints:
    # (several lines of code here)
    squared = map(lambda x: x ** 2, numbers)
```

then everything would've been fine.

You could say I was being silly for using the same variable name in the same scope.

I wasn't. The code was fine originally -- the two `x`s weren't in the same scope.
It was only after I **moved** the inner block to a different section of the code that the problem came up (read: problem during maintenance, not development), and I didn't expect it.

Yes, *if you never make this mistake* then list comprehensions are more elegant.
But from personal experience (and from seeing others make the same mistake) I've seen it happen enough times that I think it's not worth the pain you have to go through when these bugs creep into your code.

#### Conclusion:

Use `map` and `filter`. They prevent subtle hard-to-diagnose scope-related bugs.

#### Side note:

Don't forget to consider using `imap` and `ifilter` (in `itertools`) if they are appropriate for your situation!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  It hadn't explicitly occurred to me that list comprehension was in the same scope and could be an issue.  With that said, I think some of the other answers make it clear that list comprehension should be the default approach most of the time but that this is something to remember.  This is also a good general reminder to keep functions (and thus scope) small and have thorough unit tests and use assert statements.

Comment: Or always use generator and when you cannot, you could still use `list(x+2 for x in objs)`. Right?

Comment: In my opinion, this one reason is a petty example for making such a bold claim in the first line.  It's a completely invalid rationale in python 3, and even in 2.x it is not exactly a subtle bug for anyone that has used python more than a few months.  It's probably the most well-known trap, after the mutable default

Comment: @wim: This was only about Python 2, although it applies to Python 3 if you want to stay backwards-compatible. I knew about it and I'd been using Python for a while now (yes, more than just a few months), and yet it happened to me. I've seen others who are smarter than me fall into the same trap. If you're so bright and/or experienced that this isn't a problem for you then I'm happy for you, I don't think most people are like you. If they were, there wouldn't be such an urge to fix it in Python 3.

Comment: I'm sorry but you wrote this in late 2012, well after python 3 is on the scene, and the answer reads like you're recommending an otherwise unpopular style of python coding just because you got bitten by a bug while cutting-and-pasting code.  I never claimed to be bright or experienced, I just don't agree that the bold claim is justified by your reasons.

Comment: @wim: Huh? Python 2 is still used in a lot of places, the fact that Python 3 exists doesn't change that. And when you say "it's not exactly a subtle bug for anyone that has used Python more than a few months" that sentence literally means "this only concerns inexperienced developers" (clearly not you). And for the record, you clearly didn't read the answer because I said in *bold* that I was **moving**, not copying, code. Copy-paste bugs are pretty uniform across languages. This kind of bug is more unique to Python because of its scoping; it's subtler & easier to forget about and miss.

Comment: It is still not a logical reason for switching to `map` and/or `filter`.  If anything, the most direct and logical translation to avoid your problem is not to `map(lambda x: x ** 2, numbers)` but rather to a generator expression `list(x ** 2 for x in numbers)` which doesn't leak, as JeromeJ has already pointed out.  Look Mehrdad, don't take a downvote so personally, I just strongly disagree with your reasoning here.

Comment: @wim: Well I mean if you disagree then you disagree, there's not much I can do except counter your points. Regarding the generator, it's still not any better because the list has to undergo lots of reallocations (whereas map knows how long the list will be a priori). Frankly, if you're using a generator then you should be using `imap`, not `map`, which changes the question entirely. But if you just want to find a reason to pick on the answer then just keep your downvote... I don't have much else to say honestly.

Comment: where is `imap` and `ifilter` ?

Comment: Hi I'm reading this in 2019, and still use Python 2 at work. However, I think the code in the example is not very good since you're shadowing the variable x in the list comprehension. In my opinion it's always best to use different variables for each iterator

Comment: @franksands: You only find it "best" because of this massive pitfall, which is kind of the point. Otherwise it's pretty ridiculous to have `for i`, `for j`, `for k`, `for l` in completely disjoint iterators just to avoid reusing variable names, and you very quickly run out of reasonable variable names that way. Which you can avoid if you don't use comprehensions.

Comment: @Mehrdad Actually I got this habit when coding in Java many years ago. As for running out of variable names, I never had more than 3 nested loops. Also, I avoid using i, j, k. I prefer descriptive names like "for book in books" and etc

Comment: @Mehrdad In the example in your answer the list comprehension is inside the loop, that's what I meant by nested loops.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, I read the whole answer. Look, I'm not saying your answer is wrong, I was just sharing my experience on the matter, that's all. I never had that problem.

Comment: I never had this problem, today I learned. Performance-wise, on 2021-11-29 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Python 3.8 `map` is 7x faster on the first original `timeit` example and 3.5x on the second.

Comment: It may be worth to mention that this behavior does not appear in Python 3: the x variable is **not** overwritten.

Answer (score 53):

Actually, `map` and list comprehensions behave quite differently in the Python 3 language. Take a look at the following Python 3 program:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x
squares = map(square, [1, 2, 3])
print(list(squares))
print(list(squares))
```

You might expect it to print the line "[1, 4, 9]" twice, but instead it prints "[1, 4, 9]" followed by "[]". The first time you look at `squares` it seems to behave as a sequence of three elements, but the second time as an empty one.

In the Python 2 language `map` returns a plain old list, just like list comprehensions do in both languages. The crux is that the return value of `map` in Python 3 (and `imap` in Python 2) is not a list - it's an iterator!

The elements are consumed when you iterate over an iterator unlike when you iterate over a list. This is why `squares` looks empty in the last `print(list(squares))` line.

To summarize:

- **When dealing with iterators you have to remember that they are stateful and that they mutate as you traverse them.**
- Lists are more predictable since they only change when you explicitly mutate them; they are *containers*.
- And a bonus: numbers, strings, and tuples are even more predictable since they cannot change at all; they are *values*.

Comment: this is probably the best argument for list comprehensions. pythons map is not the functional map but the crippled red-headed stepchild of a functional implementation. Very sad, because I really dislike comprehensions.

Comment: @semiomant I would say lazy map (like in python3) is more 'functional' than eager map (like in python2). For example, map in Haskell is lazy (well, everything in Haskell is lazy...). Anyway, lazy map is better for chaining maps - if you have a map applied to map applied to map, you have a list for each of intermediate map calls in python2, whereas in python3 you have just one resulting list, so its more memory efficient.

Comment: I guess what I want is for `map` to produce a data structure, not an iterator. But maybe lazy iterators are easier than lazy data structures. Food for thought. Thanks @MnZrK

Comment: You want to say map returns an iterable, not an iterator.

Answer (score 22):

Here is one possible case:

```
map(lambda op1,op2: op1*op2, list1, list2)
```

versus:

```
[op1*op2 for op1,op2 in zip(list1,list2)]
```

I am guessing the zip() is an unfortunate and unnecessary overhead you need to indulge in if you insist on using list comprehensions instead of the map.  Would be great if someone clarifies this whether affirmatively or negatively.

Comment: "[op1*op2 from op1,op2 in zip(list1,list2)]" | s/form/for/

And an equivalent list with out zip: (less readable)[list1[i]*list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]

Comment: Should be "for" not "from" in your second code quote, @andz, and in @weakish's comment too. I thought I had discovered a new syntactical approach to list comprehensions... Darn.

Comment: to add a very late comment, you can make `zip` lazy by using `itertools.izip`

Comment: @tcaswell No longer needed in Python 3000.

Comment: @JeromeJ 2.x will be around for a long time.

Comment: @tcaswell yup* but people had to know. And if they are using Python 3000, I have been saving their time: no need to look for the information or using `itertools.izip` when it's not even required for them, that would have been dumb. * Even though this also depends on us. Python3, IMO at the very least, is already ready (so we can push people using it) but I now this isn't the only 'prob'…

Comment: In map case both lists must have the same length, with zip is not necessary(zip truncate extra elements in larger list)

Comment: I think I still prefer `map(operator.mul, list1, list2)`. It's on these very simple left side expressions that comprehensions get clumsy.

Comment: I hadn't realized that map could take several iterables as inputs for its function and could thus avoid a zip.

Comment: Aside from performance issues, the key point here is that `map` can automatically (if you think it's good) or *implicitly* (if you think it's bad) pair up the arguments, whereas the equivalent list comprehension requires calling `zip`. This is overlooked far too often.

Answer (score 21):

If you plan on writing any asynchronous, parallel, or distributed code, you will probably prefer `map` over a list comprehension -- as most asynchronous, parallel, or distributed packages provide a `map` function to overload python's `map`.  Then by passing the appropriate `map` function to the rest of your code, you may not have to modify your original serial code to have it run in parallel (etc).

Comment: How about this https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/tests/test_map.py and this https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/tests/test_star.py?

Comment: Python's multiprocessing module does this: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Thank you for being the only person who mentioned the big advantage of map in parallel code.

Answer (score 18):

I find list comprehensions are generally more expressive of what I'm trying to do than `map` - they both get it done, but the former saves the mental load of trying to understand what could be a complex `lambda` expression.

There's also an interview out there somewhere (I can't find it offhand) where Guido lists `lambda`s and the functional functions as the thing he most regrets about accepting into Python, so you could make the argument that they're un-Pythonic by virtue of that.

Comment: Yeah, sigh, but Guido's original intention to remove lambda altogether in Python 3 got a barrage of lobbying against it, so he went back on it despite my stout support -- ah well, guess lambda's just too handy in many *SIMPLE* cases, the only problem is when it exceeds the bounds of *SIMPLE* or gets assigned to a name (in which latter case it's a silly hobbled duplicate of def!-).

Comment: The interview you are thinking about is this one: http://www.amk.ca/python/writing/gvr-interview, where Guido says *"Sometimes I've been too quick in accepting contributions, and later realized that it was a mistake. One example would be some of the functional programming features, such as lambda functions. lambda is a keyword that lets you create a small anonymous function; built-in functions such as map, filter, and reduce run a function over a sequence type, such as a list."*

Comment: @Alex, I don't have your years of experience, but I've seen far more over-complicated list comprehensions than lambdas. Of course, abusing language features is always a difficult temptation to resist.  It's interesting that list comprehensions (empirically) seem more prone to abuse than lambdas, though I'm not sure why that should be the case.  I'll also point out that "hobbled" isn't always a bad thing.  Reducing the scope of "things this line might be doing" can sometimes make it easier on the reader.  For example, the `const` keyword in C++ is a great triumph along these lines.

Comment: > guido .   Which is another piece of evidence  that Guido is out of his mind.  Of course `lambda`'s have been made so lame (no statements..) that they're difficult to use and limited anyways.

Comment: The amk.ca link was broken for me, but I think I found the same interview at https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2959

Answer (score 16):

So since Python 3, [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is an iterator, you need to keep in mind what do you need: an iterator or `list` object.

As @AlexMartelli already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/3124746), `map()` is faster than list comprehension only if you don't use `lambda` function.

I will present you some time comparisons.

<sub>Python 3.5.2 and CPython
I've used [Jupiter notebook](https://ipython.org/notebook.html) and especially [`%timeit`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) built-in magic command

**Measurements**: s == 1000 ms == 1000 * 1000 µs = 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ns</sub>

Setup:

```
x_list = [(i, i+1, i+2, i*2, i-9) for i in range(1000)]
i_list = list(range(1000))
```

Built-in function:

```
%timeit map(sum, x_list)  # creating iterator object
# Output: The slowest run took 9.91 times longer than the fastest. 
# This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 277 ns per loop

%timeit list(map(sum, x_list))  # creating list with map
# Output: 1000 loops, best of 3: 214 µs per loop

%timeit [sum(x) for x in x_list]  # creating list with list comprehension
# Output: 1000 loops, best of 3: 290 µs per loop
```

`lambda` function:

```
%timeit map(lambda i: i+1, i_list)
# Output: The slowest run took 8.64 times longer than the fastest. 
# This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 325 ns per loop

%timeit list(map(lambda i: i+1, i_list))
# Output: 1000 loops, best of 3: 183 µs per loop

%timeit [i+1 for i in i_list]
# Output: 10000 loops, best of 3: 84.2 µs per loop
```

There is also such thing as generator expression, see [PEP-0289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#the-details). So i thought it would be useful to add it to comparison

```
%timeit (sum(i) for i in x_list)
# Output: The slowest run took 6.66 times longer than the fastest. 
# This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 495 ns per loop

%timeit list((sum(x) for x in x_list))
# Output: 1000 loops, best of 3: 319 µs per loop

%timeit (i+1 for i in i_list)
# Output: The slowest run took 6.83 times longer than the fastest. 
# This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 506 ns per loop

%timeit list((i+1 for i in i_list))
# Output: 10000 loops, best of 3: 125 µs per loop
```

#### You need `list` object:

Use list comprehension if it's custom function, use `list(map())` if there is builtin function

#### You don't need `list` object, you just need iterable one:

Always use `map()`!

Answer (score 2):

I ran a quick test comparing three methods for invoking the method of an object. The time difference, in this case, is negligible and is a matter of the function in question (see @Alex Martelli's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/6557588)). Here, I looked at the following methods:

```py
# map_lambda
list(map(lambda x: x.add(), vals))

# map_operator
from operator import methodcaller
list(map(methodcaller("add"), vals))

# map_comprehension
[x.add() for x in vals]
```

I looked at lists (stored in the variable `vals`) of both integers (Python `int`) and floating point numbers (Python `float`) for increasing list sizes. The following dummy class `DummyNum` is considered:

```
class DummyNum(object):
    """Dummy class"""
    __slots__ = 'n',

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def add(self):
        self.n += 5
```

Specifically, the `add` method. The `__slots__` attribute is a simple optimization in Python to define the total memory needed by the class (attributes), reducing memory size.
Here are the resulting plots.

[image: Performance of mapping Python object methods]

As stated previously, the technique used makes a minimal difference and you should code in a way that is most readable to you, or in the particular circumstance. In this case, the list comprehension (`map_comprehension` technique) is fastest for both types of additions in an object, especially with shorter lists.

Visit [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cikfyFGh) for the source used to generate the plot and data.

Comment: As already explained in other answers, `map` is faster only if the function is called in the exact same way (i.e. `[*map(f, vals)]` vs. `[f(x) for x in vals]`). So `list(map(methodcaller("add"), vals))` is faster than `[methodcaller("add")(x) for x in vals]`. `map` may not be faster when the looping counterpart uses a different calling method that can avoid some overhead (e.g. `x.add()` avoids the `methodcaller` or lambda expression overhead). For this specific test case, `[*map(DummyNum.add, vals)]` would be faster (because `DummyNum.add(x)` and `x.add()` have basically the same performance).

Comment: By the way, explicit `list()` calls are slightly slower than list comprehensions. For a fair comparison you need to write `[*map(...)]`.

Comment: @GZ0 thanks for the great feedback! All makes sense, and I was unaware that `list()` calls increased overhead. Should've spent more time reading through the answers. I will re-run these tests for a fair comparison, however negligible the differences may be.

Answer (score 2):

I timed some of the results with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) (a project of mine).

As others have noted, `map` really only returns an iterator so it's a constant-time operation. When realizing the iterator by `list()`, it's on par with list comprehensions. Depending on the expression, either one might have a slight edge but it's hardly significant.

Note that arithmetic operations like `x ** 2` are *much* faster in NumPy, especially if the input data is already a NumPy array.

`hex`:

[image]

`x ** 2`:

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plots:

```py
import perfplot


def standalone_map(data):
    return map(hex, data)


def list_map(data):
    return list(map(hex, data))


def comprehension(data):
    return [hex(x) for x in data]


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: list(range(n)),
    kernels=[standalone_map, list_map, comprehension],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(20)],
    equality_check=None,
)
b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

```py
import perfplot
import numpy as np


def standalone_map(data):
    return map(lambda x: x ** 2, data[0])


def list_map(data):
    return list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, data[0]))


def comprehension(data):
    return [x ** 2 for x in data[0]]


def numpy_asarray(data):
    return np.asarray(data[0]) ** 2


def numpy_direct(data):
    return data[1] ** 2


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: (list(range(n)), np.arange(n)),
    kernels=[standalone_map, list_map, comprehension, numpy_direct, numpy_asarray],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(20)],
    equality_check=None,
)
b.save("out2.png")
b.show()
```

Comment: This is missing a whole of context: What hardware was it run on (CPU, [microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_(microarchitecture)) type, number of cores, [L1 cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Multi-level_caches) size, L2 cache size, L3 cache size, clock frequency, total physical RAM, etc.)? Operating system (incl. 'edition', version, and patch level/build #). Version of Python, what [Python interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython), versions of the Python libraries, compilation/optimisation options for the Python interpreter, etc. Under what conditions?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I don't think those you mention matter, since all the tests run on the same computer

Comment: The `standalone_map` code is merely instantiating a `map` object and doesn't perform any iteration - i.e., the computation of the hex/square values never actually happens. This explains the performance results, of course. It doesn't seem very useful to include this in the plots.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code by @alex-martelli but found some discrepancies

```
python -mtimeit -s "xs=range(123456)" "map(hex, xs)"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 218 nsec per loop

python -mtimeit -s "xs=range(123456)" "[hex(x) for x in xs]"
10 loops, best of 5: 19.4 msec per loop
```

map takes the same amount of time even for very large ranges while using list comprehension takes a lot of time as is evident from my code. So apart from being considered "unpythonic", I have not faced any performance issues relating to usage of map.

Comment: This is a very old question, and the answer you are referring to was very likely written in reference to Python 2, where `map` returns a list. In Python 3, `map` is lazily evaluated, so simply calling `map` doesn't compute any of the new list elements, hence why you get such short times.

Comment: I think you are using Python 3.x When I asked this question Python 3 had only recently been released and Python 2.x  was very much the standard.

Answer (score 1):

#### Performance measurement

[image]

Image Source: Experfy

You can see for yourself which is better between - list comprehension and the *map* function.

(list comprehension takes less time to process 1 million records when compared to a map function.)

Comment: It's unclear what exact code was run or how large the samples were. Anyway, the big difference between the for-loop and map seems incorrect.

Comment: The source reference is not sufficiently accurate. Where precisely was it taken from? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65723150/edit), not here in comments (but ************ ***without*** ************ "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

I consider that the most Pythonic way is to use a list comprehension instead of `map` and `filter`. The reason is that list comprehensions are clearer than `map` and `filter`.

```
In [1]: odd_cubes = [x ** 3 for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 1] # using a list comprehension

In [2]: odd_cubes_alt = list(map(lambda x: x ** 3, filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, range(10)))) # using map and filter

In [3]: odd_cubes == odd_cubes_alt
Out[3]: True
```

As you an see, a comprehension does not require extra `lambda` expressions as `map` needs. Furthermore, a comprehension also allows filtering easily, while `map` requires `filter` to allow filtering.

Answer (score 0):

My use case:

```
def sum_items(*args):
    return sum(args)


list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [1, 2, 3]

list_of_sums = list(map(sum_items,
                        list_a, list_b))
>>> [3, 6, 9]

comprehension = [sum(items) for items in iter(zip(list_a, list_b))]
```

I found myself starting to use more map, I thought map could be slower than comp due to pass and return arguments, that's why I found this post.

I believe using map could be much more readable and flexible, especially when I need to construct the values of the list.

You actually understand it when you read it if you used map.

```
def pair_list_items(*args):
    return args

packed_list = list(map(pair_list_items,
                       lista, *listb, listc.....listn))
```

Plus the flexibility bonus.
And thank for all other answers, plus the performance bonus.